# Magento 2: Less Compilation Failing

Tags: magento2, css, less

I'm working with a set of Less CSS files I didn't write in Magento 2.  During compilation, I get the following error

```
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Infortis/base/en_US/css/custom.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/Infortis/base/en_US/css/custom.less>
#0 /path/to/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/AlternativeSource.php(155): Magento\Framework\Css\PreProcessor\Adapter\Less\Processor->processContent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
```

I know I can start debugging from line 155 in `AlternativeSource.php` -- but does anyone know what this cryptic error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may happen because the generated CSS content is empty.

See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f748e57d04f65cb0b6f3d22cfc00602e6772e51d/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php#L92.